# Rails and Phusion Passenger - can only access public folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

I just installed Phusion Passenger on my Apache Server to host a Rails 3 App.
My **vhost** file looks like that:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName markusdanek.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/loremipsum/n22/public
        <Directory /var/www/loremipsum/n22>
                AllowOverride all
                Options -Multiviews
                Options -Indexes
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

So when I try to open *loremipsum/n22* - I only get to the *404 Page* (not even the index.html)

So how can I get to my app folder (*localhost:3000/* or *localhost:3000/posts*)?
Is there anything else, I have to add to the vhost?

**My route.rb:**

```
get "home/index"

root :to => 'home#index'
```

Comment: If I want to open http://markusdanek.com/posts or my default home site at markusdanek.com (should link to "home", my start) I just get:

We're sorry, but something went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure Phusion Passenger is running properly? Set PassengerLogLevel to 1, access `example.com/n22`, then look in your global Apache error log to check whether you see any errors.